# Resharper Ultimate does not start after installation

Tags: resharper, vs-community-edition

I've just downloaded and installed Resharper for Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. However, when I launched it, Resharper toolbar menu did not appear. After checking Resharper tab in Tools/Options I saw [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNBp2.png). Attempt to resuspend it as well as restarting VS as well as reinstallation of Resharper had no effect at all.

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried restarting Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've just downloaded [previous 10.0.2 version](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207242355-Where-can-I-download-an-old-previous-ReSharper-version-) and after installation it launched well and notified me about expired license.